# Magento Main Page Error

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, fatal-error

I'm a very new in Magento and was not able to load up the website. Googled and managed to find the error log, which there are 7? Please see below.

```
#1 /home/fitnessa/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(308): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->_includeControllerClass('/home/fitnessa/...', 'Mage_Cms_IndexC...')
#2 /home/fitnessa/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(196): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->_validateControllerClassName('Mage_Cms', 'index')
#3 /home/fitnessa/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#4 /home/fitnessa/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#5 /home/fitnessa/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#6 /home/fitnessa/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#7 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Would appreciate any help.
Thanks!

Comment: Is this happened in initial setup or happened in production?

Comment: The website is already in production.

Comment: Do you have any plugins working on frontend ? please post your cms page